# Soap UI - Saml XML request not encrypting

Tags: encryption, soapui, ws-security

I have a service with federated security that I am calling.
I have inserted a keystore to the encryption field in soap UI (within WS-Security Configurations) and specified in what namespace (http://urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion) my field is that I want to encrypt but the problem is that the field never encrypts in the request. 
[image]

I have xml SAML that I have inserted which is what I am trying to encrypt which starts like this:

The request that gets generated (captured with Fiddler) is like this and it looks like it skips this SAML XML all together.

[image]

I have tried encrypting the body of the message with no problem but I cannot seem to be able to encrypt the SAML XML. 
Can someone please help me with this? What am I missing?